# How to install CKSDev on Visual Studio 2019

Tags: 2019, cksdev, visual-studio-2019

I have a new dev env with SP2016, Win2016, VS2019. Almost all of my work is development of farm solutions. On previous env I used CKSDev to speed up the deployment and simplify debugging and I want to continue, however seems that CKSDev development has frozen on VS2013 VS2017. What can I do?

Comment: what specifically are you still using CKSDev to do? I'm sure that now there are built in ways to do whatever that is.

Comment: You may be outkicking your coverage by using VS2019 to build for SharePoint 2016.  The only SharePoint-specific features that have been enhanced in VS2019 have to deal with cloud-based development such as SPFx.  You'll probably have a better SP2016 Dev environment in VS2017.  Also keep in mind that if you need VS2019 for other non-SharePoint projects, you can run both versions side-by-side.

Comment: @willman That's right I got back to VS2017 to can use the CKSDev again..

Comment: @DerekGusoff, I was wanted to use VS2019 to try it and discover the new features with myself. But I got back again to VS2017

Comment: CKSDEV not on VS2019. Intellicode no more working on VS 2017. Have to choose :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSKDEV doesn't work with VS2019. As an alternative you could try the below tool from the Visual Studio Market place.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MarcusKaseder.SPDevTools

Comment: I already tried to use this tool but isn't had any impact for me

Comment: If my answer has helped you kindly upvote and Mark it as answer so that it will help others too.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the extension working on VS2022 .

I uploaded the extension here: https://bit.ly/3rNF6qo (Use at your own risk)

Comment: I've modified `extension.vsixmanifest` and `catalog.json` files so the extension would be compatible with VS 2019 and then installed it. However when I started VS, I got many exceptions like this:

`Unhandled exception occurred while creating instance of component for contract: ISharePointProjectExtension. Exception: InvalidCastException. Message: Unable to cast object of type 'CKS.Dev2017.VisualStudio.SharePoint.Environment.ActivateSelectedFeaturesProjectExtension' to type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.ISharePointProjectExtension'.`

What is the reason for this?